# Cannot map a network drive in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, ftp, network-shares, network-drive

I know there are many topics, all with same problem, but all the answers seem irrelevant.

I have a ftp server/site and I am trying to map it to a drive in Windows 7...

Whatever I type as FTP address it says that path in invalid.
For the particular test from the image, I had no problem logging to that ftp server with Filezilla in 5 seconds setup. But this seems like an overwhelming task for Windows 7.
Any ideas? I am hoping someone can point a bug and a patch/fix, because it looks like a bug.

**The folder you entered does not appear to be valid. Please chose another.**

That service that people talk about (`Web Client`) is started, if that matters.

Edit: when I view examples is mentions: `ftp://ftp.microsoft.com` and if I type exactly that, it instantly says that it is an invalid path.

[image: sample error image]

Comment: Is there a share for the FTP? Is it really using FTP or simulating FTP?

Comment: Have you tried mapping a subfolder? Also, that IP is the same IP that I assign my desktop computer. Halo fan?

Comment: @AthomSfere I can see the folders when I login with Filezilla, is that what you meant by having "shares" on the FTP ?!

Comment: The problem seems to be a bug in windows, when I view examples is mentions: "ftp://ftp.microsoft.com" and if I type that it instantly says that it is an invalid path.

Comment: ftp.microsoft.com is an invalid path... What I meant earlier is you don't generally share the machine root as anything. A share is generally \\ipAddressorHOST\ShareName for example, many times you will do an FTP share the same, ftp://server/ftpFolder and use DNS to direct from there. But... What OS is the FTP server running also?

Comment: Also, on your latest update. ftp://ftp.microsoft.com is valid... Sorry for the confusion earlier

Comment: I tested with different servers, one is CentOS with Plesk web panel, another one is a ftp server on mobile device, both working with Filezilla from same client computer. I don't understand this Microsoft OS, can't Windows just connect to [ip/domain, port, user, pass] ? Very irritating from an OS that is supposed to be for the dummy masses. The local file sharing settings is also a complete chaos in my opinion.

Comment: It is definitely different in Windows, but also ftp is not common for the masses. You are also looking at very real and different architectures in file structure, security, interoperability... So there are a lot of strange things when you look at older less frequently used protocols.

Comment: Windows cannot map a FTP location as a drive by default. You need 3rd party software to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Enable NTLM Authentication: Most obvious or probably answer to me.

Open regedit and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
```

Once there, right click the Lsa key and click new --> DWORD. Name the DWORD LmCompatibilityLevel and set the value to 1

Close all open browsers and then try again to access the FTP share.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried flushing the ARP cache? It's an unlikely, but possible, cause. Open an administrator version of cmd.exe and run this string: "netsh interface ip delete arpcache"

edit: and then try adding the location again. Irrelevant, the OP already contacted me directly.

Update: Are you checking the ""Connect using different credentials" box? And are you being prompted for the login info, or does the error appear immediately upon clicking "Finish"?

Comment: And then do what? This appears to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @apraetor no, it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score -1):

Found the fix on different thread, resolves the issue

I found a fix on this website: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieitprocurrentver/thread/3d74bc03-b0c4-4ec1-88df-b938ec82c159

> Many thanks to TerkildHolst who had the solution for Windows 7!  It
>   seems that Google Chrome causes this problem.  To fix, copy the
>   following bold text.  Save it to a text file.  Change the text file
>   name to ftp.reg.  Double click the file and voila!
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp]
> @="URL:File Transfer Protocol"
> "AppUserModelID"="Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default"
> "EditFlags"=dword:00000002
> "FriendlyTypeName"="@C:\\Windows\\system32\\ieframe.dll,-905"
> "ShellFolder"="{63da6ec0-2e98-11cf-8d82-444553540000}"
> "Source Filter"="{E436EBB6-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770}"
> "URL Protocol"=""
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp\DefaultIcon]
> @=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
>   00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,75,00,72,00,\
>   6c,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,30,00,00,00
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp\shell]
> @="open"
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp\shell\open]
> ```

Comment: You really should provide proper formatting to this answer.  You should also quote and cite your reference link.  Anything not within a quotation block is assumed to be your own original words.  *Its clear from your answer that isn't the case.*

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: @Walmart Fixed. There is a **very intermittent** error in [SOUP](https://github.com/vyznev/soup) which breaks the links inserted by [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). My original source is correct until it is pasted :/

Comment: @DavidPostill Ah, I see... I didn't know about that tool, looks interesting though. I'll check it out someday if I ever get some time!!